# Ruby 1.9.3-p140 - Maximum number of threads in a Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, fibers

I'm playing with Thread and I discovered that I cannot run 10000 threads.

It gives me the following error:

```
        threading.rb:23:in `initialize': can't create Thread (35) (ThreadError)
        from threading.rb:23:in `new'
        from threading.rb:23:in `block in <main>'
        from threading.rb:22:in `times'
        from threading.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

Then I tried to see what's the maximum number and when I make up to 2046 threads, Ruby will run the code.

Why 2046? It appears to follow a pattern of memory like 512, 1024, 2046...

The threading.rb code:

```
    threads = []
    counter = 1000

    ARGV.each do |a|
      counter = a.to_i
    end

    lines = 0

    counter.times do |i|
      puts "This is index number #{i}."
    end

    puts "You've just seen the normal printing and serial programming.\n\n"

    counter.times do |i|
      Thread.new do
        some_number = Random.rand(counter)
        sleep 1
        puts "I'm thread number #{i}. My random number is #{some_number}.\n"
        lines += 1
      end
    end

    messaged = false
    while lines < counter
      puts "\nWaiting to finish.\n" unless messaged
      print '.'
      puts "\n" if lines == counter
      messaged = true
    end

    puts "\nI've printed #{lines} lines.\n"
    puts "This is end of the program."
```

Comment: What OS are you running on ? Try `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` on Linux for instance.

Comment: Ruby does not support thread madness. Try another approach or another language.

Comment: I'm using MacOS Lion Mountain. I don't know how to see that.

Comment: Tass, I also thought that Ruby doesn't support thread but when I did this compared to the same code without Thread, the difference was night and day.

This same code without Thread would take at least 1000 seconds to run because of each sleep 1.

With thread, it took just 1.8 ~ 2 seconds as measured with time ruby threading.rb.

The issue is with the maximum amount of threads. I'm running on a MPB i7 with 8G RAM running 1.9.3-p140 version.

I also tried using Fiber but the process took over 1000 seconds just like a code without Thread. It shows that Fiber is just a task management system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X limits the number of threads a process can spawn to 2046. This applies to Ruby as well.

Source & full explanation: ["How many threads is too many?"](http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7970125-how-many-threads-is-too-many)

> On OSX, there's a hard limit on the number of threads that one process can spawn. On recent versions, **that limit is somewhere around 2000 threads.**
>
> ...
>
> If I run this same bit of code **on a Linux machine, I'm able to spawn 10,000 threads** without blinking. So, it's possible to spawn a lot of threads, but you probably don't want to.

Here's a test program you can run to see the limit.

```
1.upto(10_000) do |i|
  Thread.new { sleep }
  puts i
end
```